# Set windows 10 settings via batch script?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I update Win10 on a regular basis and in the meantime I always defer updates via Windows Update Settings > Advanced options > Pause updates [(green in the attached picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1PwS.png)  to the latest available date, so my machine doesn't bother me with unplanned restarts.

Currently, I set the option manually after each restart. It occurred to me that this could be done automated via some script scheduled to run after a reboot. Problem is, I don't know how and what setting to change.